# CentOS 6.3: logrotate and btmp

Tags: centos, cron, logrotate

I had to configure logrotate on a server configured by other system-network administration. First of all I detected that there is no crond, so I had to install `sudo yum install vixie-cron`. All other setup seems ok `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate` file exists. Next I ran `sudo logrotate -d -f logrotate.conf` to check how it will works. At the end of execution I see this:

```
rotating pattern: /var/log/btmp  forced from command line (1 rotations)
empty log files are rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/btmp
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/btmp, log->rotateCount is 1
dateext suffix '-20131004'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
glob finding old rotated logs failed
renaming /var/log/btmp to /var/log/btmp-20131004
creating new /var/log/btmp mode = 0600 uid = 0 gid = 22
```

But nothing happens with `/var/log/btmp` still same size, and `/var/log/btmp-20131004` not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told it not to.  From the `man` page on logrotate:

> ```
>    -d, --debug
>           Turns on debug mode and implies -v.  In debug mode, no changes
>           will be made to the logs or to the logrotate state file.
> ```

Note "`no changes will be made to the logs`".